# Binding display paper-datatable-api to array after succesful response in polymer 2.0

Tags: polymer, polymer-2.x

I'm trying to display table of data with paper-datatable-api, https://github.com/RoXuS/paper-datatable-api. This data comes with some json response from server, similar likes this:

```
[{"diklat":"Test 5","penyelenggara":"BPSDMD Provinsi Jateng","peserta":2,"year":"2018"}, 
{"diklat":"Test 4","penyelenggara":"BPSDMD Provinsi Jateng","peserta":1,"year":"2018"},
{"diklat":"Test 3","penyelenggara":"BKD Provinsi Jateng","peserta":2,"year":"2018"},
{"diklat":"Test 1","penyelenggara":"BPSDMD Provinsi Jateng","peserta":2,"year":"2018"}]
```

and some input form within paper-dialog to input some data.

The data was being display correctly in paper-datatable-api table, and input works too.
The problems i was trying to grasp was, how i can bind to displayed data within table to array automatically after successfull submit...? so, the table automatically displayed with new data added.

For now, i should hard refresh (F5) to display new list of table data after submiting the form.

Here the polymer custom components i'm using:

Components to display and input data using paper-datatable-api

```
<link rel="import" href="add-form.html">

<dom-module id="train-list">
<template>
<style include="iron-flex iron-flex-alignment"></style>
<style include="shared-styles">
  :host {
    display: block;
    padding: 5px;
     }
</style>

<iron-ajax
    id="reqTr"
    auto
    url="http://127.0.0.1:5000/rekap"
    handle-as="json"
    on-response="handleResponse"
    >
</iron-ajax>

<paper-dialog id="addTrainDialog">
    <paper-dialog-scrollable>
    <div class="card">
    <h1>Add diklat</h1> 
        <add-form></add-form>
    </div>      
    </paper-dialog-scrollable>
</paper-dialog>

<!-- Create a floating action button -->
<paper-fab 
    icon='add' 
    style='position:absolute; bottom: 30px; right:24px'
on-click='showAddTrainDialog'>
</paper-fab>

<paper-datatable-api paginate data="{{trainings}}">
<paper-datatable-api-column header="Diklat" draggable-column property="diklat">
<template>
  <span>{{value}}</span>
</template>
</paper-datatable-api-column>
<paper-datatable-api-column header="Penyelenggara" property="penyelenggara">
<template>
  <span>{{value}}</span>
</template>
</paper-datatable-api-column>
    <paper-datatable-api-column header="Peserta" property="peserta">
<template>
  <span>{{value}}</span>
</template>
</paper-datatable-api-column>
    <paper-datatable-api-column header="Tahun" property="year">
<template>
  <span>{{value}}</span>
</template>
</paper-datatable-api-column>
</paper-datatable-api>

</template>

<script>
class TrainList extends Polymer.Element {
  static get is() { return 'train-list'; }
    static get properties() {
        return {
            trainings: {
                type: Array,
                notify: true
                }
            }
    }

    handleResponse(data) {
            this.trainings = data.detail.response;
    }

    showAddTrainDialog() {
        this.$.addTrainDialog.open();
            }
    }

window.customElements.define(TrainList.is, TrainList);
</script>
</dom-module>
```

Here, the custom component of `add-form`:

```
<dom-module id="add-form">
<template>
    <style include="shared-styles">
        :host {
    display: block;
    padding: 5px;
        }
    </style>
    <iron-ajax
  id="addTrainAjax"
  method="post"
  content-type="application/json"
  handle-as="text"
  on-response="handleResponse"
  on-error="handleError">
</iron-ajax>

    <iron-form id="addTrainForm">
        <form>
            <template is="dom-if" if="[[error]]">
        <p class="alert-error"><strong>Error:</strong> [[error]]</p>
    </template>
                <paper-input name="name" type="text" value="{{formData.name}}" placeholder="Nama Diklat" auto-validate required error-message="Input title diklat!!"></paper-input>
        <paper-input name="description" type="text" value="{{formData.description}}" placeholder="Deskripsi" auto-validate required error-message="Input deskripsi diklat!!"></paper-input>

                <paper-dropdown-menu label="Kategory" selected-item="{{selectedItem}}" selected-item-label="{{selected}}" auto-validate required error-message="Pilih satu!!">
                    <paper-listbox   class="dropdown-content" slot="dropdown-content" attr-for-selected="value" selected="{{formData.category}}">
                        <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[categories]]">
                            <paper-item value="[[item.id]]">[[item.id]] - [[item.category_name]]</paper-item>
                        </template>
                </paper-listbox>
                </paper-dropdown-menu>
                <input is="iron-input" name="category" type="hidden" value$="[[formData.category]]">    

        <paper-input name="begin" type="date" value="{{formData.begin}}" placeholder="Mulai" auto-validate required error-message="Input mulai diklat!!"></paper-input>
        <paper-input name="end" type="date" value="{{formData.end}}" placeholder="Kelar" auto-validate required error-message="Input selesai diklat!!"></paper-input>

                <paper-dropdown-menu label="Penyelenggara" selected-item="{{selectedItem}}" selected-item-label="{{selected}}" required auto-validate error-message="Pilih satu!!">
                    <paper-listbox  class="dropdown-content" slot="dropdown-content" attr-for-selected="value" selected="{{formData.penyelenggara}}">
                        <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[penyelenggara]]">
                            <paper-item value="[[item.id]]">[[item.id]] - [[item.short_name]]</paper-item>
                        </template>
                </paper-listbox>
                </paper-dropdown-menu>
                <input is="iron-input" name="penyelenggara" type="hidden" value$="[[formData.penyelenggara]]">

                <paper-input name="location" type="text" value="{{formData.location}}" placeholder="Location" auto-validate required error-message="Input selesai diklat!!"></paper-input>
        <paper-input name="address" type="text" value="{{formData.address}}" placeholder="Address" auto-validate required error-message="Input alamat diklat!!"></paper-input>
        <paper-input name="city" type="text" value="{{formData.city}}" placeholder="City" auto-validate required error-message="Input city diklat!!"></paper-input>
        <paper-input name="jp" type="number" value="{{formData.jp}}" placeholder="JP" auto-validate required error-message="Input jampel diklat!!"></paper-input>

                <div class="wrapper-btns">
            <paper-button id="send" raised class="primary" on-tap="postProcessing">Send to server ..</paper-button>
        </div>
            </form>
        </iron-form>

</template>

<script>
    class AddForm extends Polymer.Element {
        static get is () { 
            return 'add-form'; 
        }

        constructor() {
    super();
    this._submitted = false;
    this._presubmitted = false;
  }

        ready() {
    super.ready();
    this.$.addTrainForm.addEventListener('iron-form-submit', function() {
        this._submitted = true;
        }.bind(this));
    this.$.addTrainForm.addEventListener('iron-form-presubmit', function() {
        this._presubmitted = true;
        }.bind(this));
    this.$.addTrainForm.addEventListener('iron-form-response', function() {
        console.log(this._submitted);
        console.log(this._presubmitted);
        }.bind(this));
            this.$.addTrainForm.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
            // Validate the entire form to see if we should enable the `Submit` button.
                this.$.send.disabled = !this.$.addTrainForm.validate();
            }.bind(this));
    }

  static get properties() {
    return {
        categories: {
            type: Array,
            value: [
                {"id":1, "category_name": "Diklat Teknis"},
                        {"id":2, "category_name": "PKP"},
                        {"id":3, "category_name": "Bimtek"},
                        {"id":4, "category_name": "Workshop"},
                        {"id":5, "category_name": "Training"},
                        {"id":6, "category_name": "Seminar"},
                        {"id":7, "category_name": "Diklat Fungsional"},
                        {"id":8, "category_name": "Diklat Kepemimpinan Tk. I"},
                        {"id":9, "category_name": "Diklat Kepemimpinan Tk. II"},
                        {"id":10, "category_name": "Diklat Kepemimpinan Tk. III"},
                        {"id":11, "category_name": "Diklat Kepemimpinan Tk. IV"},
                        {"id":12, "category_name": "Diklat Kepemimpinan Tk. V"},
                        {"id":13, "category_name": "Prajabatan"},
                        {"id":14, "category_name": "Struktural"},
                        {"id":15, "category_name": "Undefined"}
            ]
        },
            penyelenggara: {
                type: Array,
                value: [
                    {"id":1, "short_name": "BPSDMD Provinsi Jateng"},
                {"id":2, "short_name": "BKD Provinsi Jateng"},
                    {"id":3, "short_name": "Disarsip Perpus Provinsi Jateng"},
                    {"id":4, "short_name": "Inspekorat Provinsi Jateng"},
                    {"id":5, "short_name": "BKPPD Kabupaten Kebumen"},
                {"id":6, "short_name": "Bapelkes Gombong"},
                    {"id":7, "short_name": "Pusdiklat Regional Yogyakarta"},
                {"id":8, "short_name": "Balai Diklat VIII Yogyakarta"},
                    {"id":9, "short_name": "Badan Diklat Yogakarta"},
                    {"id":10, "short_name": "Pusdiklatwas BPKP Bogor"},
                    {"id":11, "short_name": "Pusdiklat Reskrim POLRI"},
                    {"id":12, "short_name": "PKP2A I LAN Bandung"},
                    {"id":13, "short_name": "LAN RI"},
                    {"id":14, "short_name": "BPSDM Kemendagri RI"},
                    {"id":15, "short_name": "Undefined"}
                ]
            },
            formData: {
                type: Object,
                value: {}
                },
            error: String
    };
  }

        _setRequestBody() {
            this.$.addTrainAjax.body = this.formData;
        }

        postProcessing() {
    this.$.addTrainAjax.url = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/trains/';
    // console.log(this.$.addTrainAjax.body)
            var addform = this.$.addTrainForm;

            if (addform.validate()) {
                this._setRequestBody();
                this.$.addTrainAjax.generateRequest();
                this.error = ""
            }
            this.error = "Isi input semua data yang dibutuhkan..."
  }

  handleResponse(event) {
    var response = JSON.parse(event.detail.response);

    //if (response.id_token) {
    //    this.error = '';
    //    this.storedUser = {
    //        name: this.formData.username,
    //        id_token: response.id_token,
    //        access_token: response.access_token,
    //        loggedin: true
    //    };
    // redirect to Secret Quotes
    //    this.set('route.path', '/trains');
    //}

            console.log("log response")
            console.log(response);

            // reset form data
            this.$.addTrainForm.reset();
    this.formData = {};
            this.error = "";        
  }

        handleError(event) {
    this.error = event.detail.request.xhr.response;
  }

    }

    //window.addEventListener('WebComponentsReady', function() {
//    window.customElements.define(AddForm.is, AddForm);
//  });
    // tanpa ini, form input tidak ditampilkan di chrome, tak tahu kenapa ...
window.customElements.define(AddForm.is, AddForm);
</script>
```

Sorry, i can't format the code correctly

Answer (score 0):

The main problem at `add-form` child element is to set the property of `trainings`. You will need to use `this.set` method to observable property changes. (So you will not need to refresh to get new value at parent). Simple, use `trainings` property has `notify:true` and define new value like: `this.set('traninigs', newTraninigsValue);` But also need to bind new value to `traninigs` at parent as :  `<add-form traninigs="{{traninigs}}"></add-form>`

[DEMO](https://codepen.io/cappittall/pen/QQzLmY).